# Capturing Openflow traffic with Wireshark in CentOS 6.7

Tags: centos, wireshark, sdn, openflow

I want to capture Openflow packets with wireshark on a CentOS 6.7 machine. Now the problem is, the wireshark I get from the Repositories with "yum install wireshark" is only version 1.8 and doesnt have a Openflow Dissector to understand Openflow. I also tried following solution:
https://www.1310nm.net/coherentlight/2017/07/25/wireshark-2-4-centos7-tldr-version/
But I get errors for example: "Error: Package: wireshark-qt-2.4.3-1.x86_64 (wireshark) Requires: libQt5Core.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit)"
Now I dont know where to download there packages, they are not found by yum.

If someone has a solution to capture openflow traffic on a CentOS 6.7 machine, I would like to hear it please.

Thank you in advance